# Should a RESTful API return data with codes or translate codes into descriptions?

Tags: javascript, rest, api

I'm developing an API that will return data to an end user.  In my server side model, I use a number of codes that have an associated lookup table to find descriptions and other related properties tied to the code.

I'm curious if there is a "Best Practice" in regards to returning data.  The options here would be:

**Option 1: Return codes and provide APIs for lookup lists**

In this scenario, you might have something like this:

```
//An API call to get a person
let person = await this.dataService.getPerson(1); //performs fetch
//{id: 1, first: "Micky", last: "Mouse", gender: 1, countryOfOrigin: "US"}

//An API call to get lookups -- returned as Map();
let genders = await this.dataService.getGenders();
let countries = await this.dataService.getCountries();

//Now I can do the following to get the definition
let gender = genders.get(person.gender);
let country = countries.get(person.countryOfOrigin).description;

 console.log("gender.description");
 console.log("country.description");
 console.log("country.isoA3");
```

**Option 2: Return an object fully populated**

```
//API call to get a person
let person = dataService.getPerson(1);
//{id: 1, 
   first: "Micky", 
   last: "Mouse", 
   gender: "Male", 
   countryOfOrigin: {
      code: "US",
      description: "United States of America",
      isoA3: "USA",
      isoN3: 840
    }
  }
```

**Option 3: Make it self referencing**

I know there is an option whereby the countryOfOrigin might be a link to another API call for a given country.  However, in my situation, most users will be requesting a large number of people as opposed to individual people and displaying those persons in a list form -- so it would be quite a hit on the server if the user had to query for 1000 people and then ping the server 1000 times to get each countryOfOrigin.

Is there a standard or best practice that would provide some direction here?

Comment: All depends on the rate the data changes, because you can make the call to genders and countries only one time and store the results in the client to re-use them later, but if security is compromised you should use the second option. Third seems the most payload-cost-able.

Comment: I would make an option for the caller. Have a default of Option 1, but allow a URL parameter for them to tell you they want Option 2. And be consistent: Option 2 has code and value for countryOfOrigin, but gender only has value, which is inconsistent. As a rule, if you're not sure which way, do both and let the customer choose.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a standard or best practice that would provide some direction here?

Not really, there are just different trade offs.

The easiest analogy I can think of on the web is java script -- should you embed the source in the page? or should you link to the source and download it separately?  "It depends" -- having the separate resource is great when you want fine grained control of the caching policy, but its lousy when caching is a liability rather than an asset.

One common approach, as noted by Preacher, is to provide different resources for the different use cases.

Another possibility is to use a single resource, but with different representations (media-types) to support the different use cases.

As far as I can tell, these are just different ways of moving the pain around.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of potential options:

**A. Use an api standard that supports embedding resources.**

I tend to use HAL for all responses, but HAL is not a great format to solve this problem. JSON:API handles this case better. It allows sending relationships along with the response, an a good JSON:API client can take those relationships and put them in a temporary cache.

The reason HAL isn't good for this is that it doesn't have a good way to de-duplicate multiple relationships. GraphQL handles this case also extremely well, but it's not REST.

**B. Attack the true cause of the issue.**

Really the issue you are describing is that you are worried that many HTTP requests will be made, and having many HTTP requests is a bad thing.

There's several ways to potentially combat this.

1. Use HTTP/2. With HTTP/2 having many smaller requests is much less of an issue as it used to be. Maybe it's not as painful as you think.
2. Use HTTP/2 Push. Push can optimize this a little bit further and remove even a bit more latency.
3. If your API is slow, choose a technology that can respond to HTTP requests even faster. Does your framework have a 100ms start-up time for every request? That's gonna be very noticable.
4. Use great cache headers. Countries don't change much. You can put very aggressive `Cache-Control` headers, letting clients keep a copy of the headers for a very long time. This will especially benefit browser clients (HTTP clients running on servers tend to not use caching much).
5. Use a good caching proxy or CDN. This is related to 4, and might make 3 unnecessary.